# 3rd Order Symplectic Integrator for N-Body Solar-System Problem

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, physics

I am doing a solar-system simulation. I am using Ruth's 3rd order [sympletic integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator) to avoid the problem of [Energy Drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_drift) (which I had with [RK4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#The_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_method)), but the  the planets quickly leave orbit, and energy is by no means conserved (just like with RK4).

[Here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAPSd.png) Ruth's Integrator.

I applied this to the N-body problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8th73.png).

To get velocity, I just did: v=p/m

Have I correctly applied this algorithm to the gravitational N-body problem?

If you need more information on how I derived this, visit my question [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36134/trouble-making-3rd-order-sympletic-integrator-for-planitary-n-body-problem-a-ha).

Comment: It should be clear that the physics at some point is not correct or realistic. Even with energy drift, the qualitative behavior of the solution over this short time frame should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was twofold: 1) I should have used norm2 instead of abs when implementing in FORTRAN 2008.

i.e.
This line: to_add=(rj-ri)big_gmasses(i)*masses(j)/((abs(rj-ri))**3.0d0)
--> to_add=(rj-ri)big_gmasses(i)*masses(j)/((norm2(rj-ri))**3.0d0)

2. My data was messed up, so I tried switching to some one else's, but I forgot to change the units when I did.

So in summary, all the math and physics above should work.